# Como executar uma função php no ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou querendo saber como posso fazer para clicar em um botão e no onclick desse botão eu chamar uma função php, disseram que tenho que usar ajax, porém não tenho conhecimento em ajax mas vou estudar, poderiam me ajudar?

```
  <button id="loadmore" onclick="<?php queryRetorno($limite*2);?>">Carregar 
   Mais</button>
```

Tentei desse jeito mas não deu, basicamente o que quero é aumentar o limite da query sql a cada vez que o botão for clicado, aqui está a função queryRetorno

```
 function queryRetorno($limite){

 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT wposts.*,(SELECT meta_value FROM      
 wp_7_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_wp_attached_file' and post_id = (SELECT      
 meta_value FROM wp_7_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_thumbnail_id' and  
 wp_7_postmeta.post_id= wposts.ID limit 1)) as imagem
 FROM wp_7_posts wposts 
 LEFT JOIN wp_7_postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
 LEFT JOIN wp_7_term_relationships ON (wposts.ID =      
 wp_7_term_relationships.object_id) 
 LEFT JOIN wp_7_term_taxonomy ON (wp_7_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =      
 wp_7_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
 where `post_type`='post' and post_status ='publish'
 LIMIT {$limite}");
 carregaImagem($sql);

 return $limite;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sim terás de fazer um httpRequest utilizando javascript(ajax) a um url que execute a tua função desejada, pois nunca podes utilizar php no javascript porque um funciona do lado do servidor(php) e outro do lado do utilizador(javascript)

**1º**
Terás de saber o url da pagina que executa a tua função php ex: (http://omeusite.com/minhafuncao.php)

**2º**
Como não podes ter php dentro do javascript ou do html, o que terás de fazer é executar uma função javascript que faça um httpRequest ao url da tua função(php)

HTML:

```
<button onclick="chamaAminhaFuncao(ColocasAquiOTeuLimit);">Executar a funcao php</button>
```

Javascript (vou utilizar JQuery para facilitar o uso do ajax):

```
var chamaAminhaFuncao = function(limit){
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "http://omeusite.com/minhafuncao.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: { limit: limit}
    });

    request.done(function( msg )
    {
        //Aqui colocas o codigo para quando tudo corre bem
    });

    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        //Aqui colocas o codigo para quando algo corre mal
    });
}
```

**Atenção, antes do teu javascript terás de incluir o jQuery no teu HTML**

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    Codigo javascript que fiz la em cima
</script>
```

**Agora no php é facil**

```
 function queryRetorno($limite){

      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT wposts.*,(SELECT meta_value FROM      
      wp_7_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_wp_attached_file' and post_id = (SELECT      
      meta_value FROM wp_7_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_thumbnail_id' and  
      wp_7_postmeta.post_id= wposts.ID limit 1)) as imagem
      FROM wp_7_posts wposts 
      LEFT JOIN wp_7_postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
      LEFT JOIN wp_7_term_relationships ON (wposts.ID =      
      wp_7_term_relationships.object_id) 
      LEFT JOIN wp_7_term_taxonomy ON (wp_7_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =      
      wp_7_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
      where `post_type`='post' and post_status ='publish'
      LIMIT {$limite}");
      carregaImagem($sql);

      return $limite;
 }

 //pegas os dados passados por post
 isset($_POST['limit'] ? $limit = ( (int) $_POST['limit'] * 2 ) : $limit = 0;

 //agora chamas a tua funcao php

 $oTeuRetorno = queryRetorno($limit);
```

Não testei mas a logica é esta e penso que está tudo a funcionar

Comment: Só uma coisa, antes de perguntar, pesquisa primeiro um pouco, pois isto é das cenas mais básicas que tens, e tal como dizes em cima, disseram-te que precisavas utilizar ajax, precisavas apenas de perder 5min a pesquisar e tinhas a tua resposta

Comment: Obrigado @Simão Lemos, Duvida.. Na url tem que ter os ** mesmo? e o código ou a função php eu chamo no request.done?

Comment: Não, sry, os ** era apenas para colocar o texto em negrito, mas parece que não posso fazer isso dentro do codigo. Vou ja corrigir

Comment: Tambem não precisas colocar o url todo, isto se a path for a mesma. Podes simplesmente colocar /minhafuncao.php

Comment: Aaah ta, @Simão Lemos mas o problema que você solucionou é outro, eu quero execultar uma função mesmo tipo tenho a pagina php e execultar a função dessa pagina

Comment: A logica está ai mas eu vou editar a resposta...

Comment: Já esta editada... mais que isto só se for ai a tua casa fazer....