# Inserir linha no MYSQL sem sair da página (usando PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Tenho um sistema de baixar músicas com um botão baixar e gostaria que ao clicar no botão, ele inserisse uma linha no banco de dados, sem sair da página.

Atualmente o que fiz é ele abrir um nova página que faz o insert:

Para cada música tem esse código na linha da tabela:

```
<form method="post" action="inseremusica.php">
<input type="text" name="id">
<button type="submit">
</form>
```

inseremusica.php

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "INSERT INTO euk_lista_downloads (idmusica, data)
VALUES ($_POST['id'], date('d/m/Y H:i:s', time()))";
$conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Faça uma chamada `Ajax`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190816/como-executar-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-php-no-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Se você tiver a possibilidade de usar `jQuery`, é possível fazer o que você deseja, habilitando uma ação no clique do download, enviando um `POST` para uma outra página `PHP`, onde lá você faz o `INSERT`, dessa forma não tendo de atualizar a página em questão.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ter um botão que chame uma função ajax. Nessa função ajax você coloca o comando:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "INSERT INTO euk_lista_downloads (idmusica, data)
VALUES ($_POST['id'], date('d/m/Y H:i:s', time()))";
$conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();
```